# Winfom with sql database

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

HI,

i am workig in c# winforms from last few months ,but i don't have much information about SQL Database.
So, i googled but couldn't find a proper tutorial or beginners guide.

Just to try and  play,I am looking to create simple windows application with sql database containing Username and Password and which will allow me to log in after verifying username and password.

Any help ??

Comment: I doubt that you googled... http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&client=firefox-a&hs=rvl&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&q=c%23+connect+to+database&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=

Comment: Putting "c# access sql database" in a search engine gave a result with the first link being "Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#" pointing to: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

Comment: and the link is really great for beginers.

Comment: @ Daniel: yes i googled,,but i was really confused with the things i read..so  i just wanted to learn the things from scratch...The link provided is not providing any help that actuly how we add database (.sdf etc)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need both SQL Server as well ADO.NET concept to begin.
Lets check the following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Beginers Guide To Access SQL SERVER from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the things you could do,

Create Sql Server database, for that you need to install `Sql server`, Sql `Server Management Studio`.
Explore `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace in .Net framework, it contains classes like `SqlConnection, SqlCommand` etc

You will find tons of tutorials on the web.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Following link will help you:

http://sharpertutorials.com/connecting-to-a-sql-server-database/

Also googling with following query will give you many links:

> connecting to sql database using c
>   sharp